# Is there a way to format an array output when doing arithmetic to multidimensional arrays

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I am writing a program to find the sum of all rows in an array but when my teacher checked it the math is right but output is badly formatted. If I had an array like this: {2, 1}, {1, 1} my code outputs 32. How do I get it to output 3 & 2 separately?

```
 public static void main(String [] args) {
      int [][] t ={ {1, 2}, {1, 1} };
      int[] sums = new int[t.length];
      int i = 0;

for (int[] row : t) {
    sums[i++] = sumArray(row);

    System.out.print(sumArray(row));
    }
}

public static int sumArray(int[] m) {

      int sum = 0;
        for (int number : m) {
            sum = sum + number;
        }
        return sum;
}
```

I am also required to not use any arithmetic operators.

Comment: Well then use a different way to print your results to the console. You only use one method to print and that one has a detailed JavaDoc description. Read that and then look what else the class, which already provides `print`, has to offer.

Comment: Okay, I'm confused as to what to do is that row is currently holding both rows in the array hence why its printing both rows together, I don't know how to make the two rows their own variables so I can print them out separately, I have only been programming for a year now so I don't have a strong understanding yet.

Comment: *"that row is currently holding both rows in the array hence why its printing both rows together"*. That's incorrect. It is your usage of `print` that causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Read about the diference between `print()` and `println()`. Try something like below and pick out the one which suits your need:

1)

```
for (int[] row : t) {
    sums[i++] = sumArray(row);
    System.out.print(sumArray(row) + " ");
}
```

2)

```
for (int[] row : t) {
    sums[i++] = sumArray(row);
    System.out.print(sumArray(row) + ", ");
}
```

3)

```
for (int[] row : t) {
    sums[i++] = sumArray(row);
    System.out.println(sumArray(row));
}
```

4)

```
for (int[] row : t) {
    sums[i++] = sumArray(row);
    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(row));
    System.out.print(" = ");
    System.out.println(sumArray(row));
}
```